# Some issue between navigation between divs and creation of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div `.content` with two divs inside (`.content-1`, `.content-2`).

Each div inside `.content` can have only two paragraphs.

So, If all `<div>`'s already have two paragraphs I want to create a new one to put there the new added paragraph.

But, Im having two problems:

-> Some issue between navigation between `<div>`'s and creation of `<div>`'s

-> When I click to add a new paragraph and a `<div>` already have two paragraphs is adding anyway

I have here an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/t7o6emuf/2/

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-1">
            <a class="left" href="">Left</a>
            <a class="right" href="">Right</a>
            <p>P1</p>
            <p>P2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-2">
            <a class="left" href="">Left</a>
            <a class="right" href="">Right</a>
            <p>P3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".left").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(".content-" + getCurrIndex(this, true)).show();
        return false;
    });
    $(".right").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(".content-" + getCurrIndex(this, false)).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"p"` at `return $(this).children("p").length !== 2;`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t7o6emuf/4/

Comment: Thanks! But with your solution when are added more divs the navigation dont work fine!

Comment: @Oscar _"But with your solution when are added more divs the navigation dont work fine! "_ ? Can describe "navigation dont work fine" ?

Comment: When are added more divs, then the next click in the navigation (left, right links)  clear the added divs.

Comment: @guest271314 I believe he is talking about click on "Left" and "Right" links.

Comment: @ndd Yes, could add `a` elements to each newly created `.content` `div`

Comment: Yes, I added that: $(".content").append("<div class='content-" + (divContentSize + 1) + "'><a href='' class='left'>left</a><a href='' class='right'>Right</a><p>" + input + "</p></div>"). And when I click in the links it clear the added divs.

Comment: @Oscar _"when I click in the links it clear the added divs"_ Can update jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: Its here: http://jsfiddle.net/t7o6emuf/10/, but in jsfiddle it seems that gives a post error.

Comment: If you go to that jsfiddle, and you click 4 times in "Add new paragraph" and then you click in the right link 2 times, then it shows the right link of the new div, if you click there it delete the added divs.

Comment: @Oscar Try adding `#` to `a` element `href` , include `e.preventDefault()` at `.left, .right` `click` handler http://jsfiddle.net/t7o6emuf/12/

Comment: Thanks, but still dont work, if you test your code now dont delete the added divs but the navigation dont works. You click in the links and nothing happens.

Comment: @Oscar _"click in the links and nothing happens."_  Try using event delegation `$(document).on("click", ".left, .right", fn)` at `.left,.right` `click` event for newly created elements `a` appended to do, cument http://jsfiddle.net/t7o6emuf/13/

Comment: @Oscar Can describe _"not working"_ ? Appear to navigate , here , when click "Left" , "Right"